# how to implement html5 in android

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am new to HTML5 and phonegap. when i googled, i came to know that html5 can use in android but i dont know how to implement html5 for android application. Is there possible to use HTML5 with phonegap or can use html5 alone in android application. I am confused with using html5 and phoengap.

when i search how to use html5 in android i got code as

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>Cupertino Streaming</title>
</head>

<body>
 <video controls src="http://[wowza-address]:1935/vod/sample.mp4/playlist.m3u8">
 </video>

</body>
</html>
```

all these code are in html5 format.with this how i use along with android application. if i need to implement whether i need to use phonegap? can anyone please help to startoff android application with html5.
Please provide some link and reference for learning html5 by myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @userSeven7s i know how to using html5 but confusion in implementing in android.

Comment: See this page for mobile HTML5 compatibility: http://mobilehtml5.org/

Answer (score 2):

you dont need to do any specific implementation for android. just create a normal html5 page and android can read it.

see [this site](http://www.networkrail.co.uk/m/) for sample implementation of html5 and css3.

Comment: for reading html5 page in android. whether i have to use phonegap or i can use webview?

Comment: just put pure html code. device will read it. no need to use any framework.